# How to count 0 when row return null

Tags: sql, group-by, count, null

I have created table from which I want to count the number work based on work status.

[image: This my table]

This is the query I have used:

```
SELECT Workid, COUNT(*)
FROM WORK WHERE STATUS = 'awarded'
GROUP BY Workid
```

Output I am getting:

[image: Output I am getting]

Output I want:

[image: Output I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause in your query:

```
WHERE STATUS = 'awarded'
```

filters out all these rows that you want to include in the results with `0` in the column `Count`.

So, you have to remove it and include the condition `STATUS = 'awarded'` inside the `COUNT()` aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Workid, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'awarded' THEN 1 END) AS Count
FROM WORK 
GROUP BY Workid;
```

This way the query aggregates on all rows of the table and will return `0` when the condition `STATUS = 'awarded'`is not satisfied for a specific `Workid`.

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Workid, SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'awarded' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM WORK 
GROUP BY Workid;
```

This assumes that all `WorkId`s have at least one row in the table, regardless of status.